# Titanium - Authenticate with Google/Twitter/Facebook - Account

Tags: oauth-2.0, titanium, twitter-oauth, facebook-authentication, google-authentication

I'm using titanium to create a social app, where people can find each other and schedule appointments for doing stuff together.

I want that users can log in with their Google,Twitter or Facebook account, but I don't know how this is usually done with Titanium.

Usually, a user is already logged in to Google, Facebook or Twitter and his accounts are saved on the device. So, theoretically, I should be able to use one of these account's information and send it to my server, which then verifies, that the user is really logged into that account by accessing the API of the account-provider.

I've seen apps that seem to do exaclty this. For example the twitter app on android.
When I don't have a twitter account and want to create an account, the twitter app suggests me to login with my google account, and already knows the gmail-address of it. Then, I just can click on "create my account" and it's authenticated. I don't even need to log into my google account again to create some access token. It seems to take the access-token from the  already logged-in google account to verify i'm really logged in.

So, I know that it is possible. What I don't know is how.

Can you give me some hints about if & how I can achieve this same logic in my titanium app?